# XMLHttpRequest of Linkedin API url returns null

Tags: javascript, oauth, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain, linkedin-api

In my javascript application i want to perform a people search on Linkedin. Since this search has to work without a user having to login to Linkedin, i'm using a javascript OAuth library and my Linkedin api key, secret key, oauth token and oauth secret token to generate a api url. This url looks like this:

http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people-search:(people:(id,first-name,last-name,picture-url,location))?first-name=John&last-name=Smith&count=4&format=json&oauth_consumer_key=XXX&oauth_token=XXX&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_timestamp=XXX&oauth_nonce=XXX&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_signature=XXX

When i directly enter the url in my browser, it provides the results i want. However, performing a javascript XMLHttpRequest of this url always returns null. In my opinion, this indicates that there must be a problem with cross-domain policy. Yet, as i have added my domain to my Linkedin app's javascript api domains, i thought no cross-domain problems would occur.

Can anybody tell me what is the problem here?

PS: This is the javascript code for the XMLHttpRequest:

```
var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET",url,true); // url = valid url like the one above
xhr.onreadystatechange=function() {
   if (xhr.readyState===4) {
      alert(xhr.responseText); // returns null
   }
};
xhr.send(null);
```

Comment: can you post your request code?

Comment: Are you trying to use CORS?

Comment: @Bergi: Unfortunately, I cannot use CORS here because Linkedin doesn't support it (http://developer.linkedin.com/forum/cors).

Comment: @xpages-noob: So how do you expect not to violate the SOP? Where is your script executed?

Comment: @Bergi: I think you are right: There does not seem to be a way around the SOP without using CORS or JSONP. Thanks for making this clear to me.